# Problem with SQL function. Data is not the same with excel file

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to count number of records with week number of 27.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM booker.o 
WHERE assigned_to_group 
IN ( 'Writing' ) 
AND create_date > '2020-11-08'
AND (DatePart(week, resolved_date) - 1)  = '27'
AND short_description = %corrective%`
```

Function: (`DatePart(week, resolved_date) - 1)` convert given date to week number.
Example of `short_description` columns: `SP-ADDITIONAL CORRECTIVE ND - EU` -Research

I would like to extract the count of records only with week 27 and with a description that includes words: , corrective".

The number of records does not equal with records from the excel file but they should. So something must be wrong with my syntax. Also column status as a filter: resolved and closed. When I use my syntax all , closed" records disappear.
Have you know any tips/solutions because I have no ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Excel screen below:

[image: View of table first column in excel]

Comment: Are you aware of MySql's [week fucntions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear)?

Comment: And that you need to wrap text data in quotes?

Comment: And the use of `%` would normally be used with the `LIKE` clause, not the `=`

Comment: Week from fucntion: (DatePart(week, resolved_date) - 1) is extracted correctly and it's compliant  with excel filewhere the data is correct.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample data, and the expected result. `AND short_description = %corrective%` does not look like valid SQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly it does not work with LIKE anstead = also

Comment: If your Excel file is the ultimate correct source of data, then probably it makes sense to add week number as a separate stored fields and not calculate it?

Comment: HINT: `AND short_description LIKE '%corrective%'`

Comment: Does MySql have a DatePart function? Also, if it does, does it return a string, or an integer? Maybe you need to compare to `27` and not `'27'`